# Merge folders in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i have two Spark streaming processes which write files into seperate folders in HDFS - 
folder1 and folder2

I want that all files will be located under folder2.
What are the best (& safe) ways to move files from folder1 to folder2 repeatidly ?

Thanks